# fortran c++ linking libraries

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, fortran

I have been trying for a while now to run a fortran code that links to a library which uses c++ routines. The code is very simple:

```
program simple_program
implicit none
#include "looptools.h"
call ltini
print *, B0(1000D0, 50D0, 80D0)
call ltexi
end
```

According to the developer it should work if you compile it with

```
gfortran -I$LT/include example.F -L$LT/lib -looptools
```

I even added -lstdc++ at the end of the line when compiling. The LT variable is set to the correct directory (where the package and libraries are installed). The problem is that it seems to ignore the C++ functions that are included in the package, so I think I am not linking properly the fortran and c++ libraries.
As this is happening wiht a very simple example and I compiled as the developer suggests, I think maybe it has to do with my version of ubuntu libraries for linking f and C++?

Comment: You maybe have a problem with c++ mangled function names.

Comment: Try `gfortran -c example.F`, then `g++ example.o .... -lgfortran`, where the ellipses are everything else that you already have.

Comment: You have a header called `looptools.h` for a library called `ooptools` ?  What is the actual filename of the library archive?

Comment: In my installation, the library dir is lib64, not lib.
@IanH, it is tricky but the actual name of the library is libooptools.a.

Comment: Thanks IanH, yes that is correct the header is looptools.h but the library is libooptools.a (the developer did this on purpose so you wrote -looptools when calling for the library). @credondo that it also true, I wrote it wrong in this blog, but I wrote it correctly in my window, lib64. Either way it does not work, the weird thing is that I can compile the c-version of the same program, calling for the fortran libraries instead with -lgfortran. But whenever I tried the opposite running a fortran program calling for c libraries, it seems it ignores them, I-ve used -lc, -lstdc++.. nothing works!

Comment: If you have a different indentation in your code, maybe the compiler assumes fixed format due to the F extension and interprets the lines starting with c as commented lines.

Comment: Thanks credondo!, actually I already realised why, I had to add -ff2c at the end because there is code in looptools generated by g77 and f2c. It took me so long to realise this. But it does have to be a .F extension in order to call for preprocessors I think.

Comment: .fpp, .FPP, .F, .FOR, .FTN, .F90, .F95, .F03 or .F08. will call the preprocessor too

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved adding -ff2c at the end in the command line, to generate code designed to be compatible with code generated by g77 and f2c